# SSIS 2015 with SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have dtsx packages which are created using SSDT 2010 (SQL Server 2012). And we have used the Package Deployment Model. Now I would want to migrate my packages to latest version of SQL 2016 & Studio 2015.

I have following 2 questions -

Can I migrate my packages to SSDT 2015 and run it on SQL Server 2016?

After migration, will I be able to run it on SQL Server 2014/2012?

Or what is the recommended combination of SSIS & SQL sever?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, combinations of SSDT/SSIS/SQL Server have always been a pain to me.
You can migrate your packages with the [SSIS Package Upgrade Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280547.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in SSDT 2015. Be prepared that some things will not be properly migrated, you'll have to walk through them one by one (that's my experience at least).
Make sure you take a backup of the packages before you start the upgrade process!

> When you open an Integration Services project that contains SQL Server
>   2008 Integration Services (SSIS) or later packages, Integration
>   Services automatically opens the SSIS Package Upgrade Wizard.

SSDT 2015 (starting from the [june update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/06/01/sql-server-data-tools-ga-update-for-june-2016/) this year) also provides support for multiple SQL Server versions, you can set your target SQL Server version in the project. At the [SSDT Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/) you can find the latest updates and changes every month.